# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties error- c# visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ui-automation

Im getting error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'AutElemMethods.Selector(AutomationElement)' and 'AutElemEx.Selector(AutomationElement)' from two of the classes that Im working with. 
How do I resolve this? 
Code:

```
public static class AutElemMethods
{       
   public static string Selector(this AutomationElement element)
    {
        AutomationElement parent = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker.GetParent(element);
        if (parent == AutomationElement.RootElement)
        {
            return $"<{element.Name()}>";
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element.Name()))
        {
            return parent.Selector() + "<>";
        }
        return $"{parent.Selector()}<{element.Name()}>";
    }
}

    public static class AutElemEx
{
    private static string Selector(this AutomationElement element)
    {
        string name = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element.Name()) ? "" : $@"'Name':'{element.Name()}',";
        string type = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element.Type()) ? "" : $@"'Type':'{element.Type()}',";
        return "{" + (name + type).Trim(',') + "}";
    }
}
```

Comment: The error indicates you have two extension methods with the same name, but in your code they have different names.

Comment: private static string Selector(this AutomationElement element)
  {
   string name = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element.Name()) ? "" : $@"'Name':'{element.Name()}',";
   string type = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element.Type()) ? "" : $@"'Type':'{element.Type()}',";
   return "{" + (name + type).Trim(',') + "}";
  }

Comment: Either put the methods inside different namespaces and only import one of them, or rename one of the methods

Comment: @sparky. Class Names are not relevant for extension methods. The Method names/signature have to be unique over all Extension Methods in all classes,just for case you don't get it. A private extension method does not make any sense at all, if you don't call it from inside the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension methods are scoped within a namespace, but not within the static class containing them. As a result, your two extension methods have the same name and arguments, so are considered the same signature by the compiler.

You have a few options.

- Rename one of the methods.
- Place them in different namespaces and
  only import the desired namespace in a given code file.
- Statically invoke the method instead of using it like an extension method, e.g.: `AutElemEx.Selector(myElement);`
- If they must be in the same namespace, you can [statically import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) only the desired extension class into a given code file, e.g. `using static MyNamespace.AutElemEx;`